# How to check if index exists in Cognitive Search?

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search

I'd like to find out whether an Index already exists in my search instance.

Previously in v10 of the library, I could do:

```
if (serviceClient.Indexes.Exists(indexName)) {...}
```

With v11, `SearchServiceClient` has been replaced by `SearchIndexClient`, which doesn't have `.Indexes` collection.

I tried code below, but it blows up with `Fields cannot be null. To clear values, call Clear. (Parameter 'value')`:

```
string match = indexClient.GetIndexNames().SingleOrDefault(i => i == indexName);
```

So what is the new way to see if an index exists?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`SearchIndexClient.GetIndexesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.searchindexclient.getindexesasync?view=azure-dotnet) for that.

Comment: I was able to get GetIndexesAsync to work - true.  But why won't GetIndexNames work?

Comment: I was able to repro. Investigating.

Comment: Looks like a bug, following up on that. In the meantime, please use `idxclient.GetIndexes().Any(index => index.Name == indexName)` to check if an index exists. I've verified this to work.

Comment: After verification, it turns out this is a known issue for which a fix is on its way. Sorry about the inconvenience, please use the workaround in the meantime.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/15590 to track the issue.